# Data returned from getStaticProps shows on the console but not displaying on page jsx

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I'm trying to re-write a project previously done in React with nextjs. I have a simple page that uses getStaticProps along it with its required ally, getStaticPaths. The issue is that the returned data (object) is available if I console log it, but doesn't show on the page jsx. I have done everything I know to do to no avail.
The getStaticProps and getStaticpaths are as follows:

```
export async function getStaticProps(context) {
    try {
    const slug = context.params.slug;
    const response = await fetch(`http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/product/${slug}/`);
    const data = await response.json();
    return {
        props: { product: data },
      };
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error)  
    }
  }



export const getStaticPaths = async () => {
    try {
    const response =  await fetch(`http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/product/list/`);
    const data = await response.json();
    const allSlugs = data.map(item => item.slug)
    const paths= allSlugs.map(slug => ({params:{slug:slug}}))
    return {
        paths,
        fallback: false,
    }
    } catch (error) {
     console.log(error)   
    }
  }
```

The page jsx is:

```
function Product({product}){
    console.log(product) // This displays the product quite alright on the console
return <div>
The following did not work (blank), and no error message
    <h2>{product.name}</h2>
    <p> {product.price}</p>
</div>
}
export default Affidavit
```

As I said, nothing got displayed on the page, yet there is no error whatsoever. But surprisingly the returned object displays on the console. Please, any idea what could be the issue here

Comment: Your component is called `Product`, and you are exporting `Affidavit`. Are you aware of that?

Comment: Yeah, I know. It's just a typo

Answer (score 0):

Could you try this instead:

```
export async function getStaticProps(context) {
    try {
    const slug = context.params.slug;
    const response = await fetch(`http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/product/${slug}/`);
    const product = await response.json();
    return {
        props: { product },
      };
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error)  
    }
  }
```

Comment: This doesn't change anything. And if you read my question, there is no problem with either getStaticprops or getStaticpaths. The problem is simply that the return data is not displaying on the page, but yet displays on the console

Answer (score 0):

You should return your html in your product component within ().

Your code would look like this:

```js
function Product({product}){
    console.log(product) // This displays the product quite alright on the console
return (
  <div>
    The following did not work (blank), and no error message
    <h2>{product.name}</h2>
    <p> {product.price}</p>
  </div>
)}
export default Affidavit
```

If this fails, please share your console.log() output.

Comment: This doesn't change anything

Comment: Also try exporting Product as the default fuction. If none of this fixes anything it could have to do with the structure of your product object being different to what you’re expecting. To rule this out we’d need to see the console.log() of your Product object